# Python Module for MySQL Workbench not working

Tags: python, mysql, plugins, module, mysql-workbench

I am currently writing an Plugin for MySQL Workbench, but when I execute it nothing happens. (no Errors)

**Code:**

```
from wb import *
import grt
import mforms

ModuleInfo = DefineModule(name= "Workbench Module", author= "OpenByte", version="1.0")


@ModuleInfo.plugin("openbyte.workbench_module", caption= "Workbench Module", input=[wbinputs.currentSQLEditor()], pluginMenu="SQL/Utilities")
@ModuleInfo.export(grt.INT, grt.classes.db_query_Editor)
def executeScript(editor):

        editor.replaceContents("test")

        return 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't see any errors that means your plugin wasn't executed, because you should get AttributeError. `db_query_Editor` doesn't have function `replaceContents`. Try something like this:

```
from wb import DefineModule, wbinputs
import grt

ModuleInfo = DefineModule(name= "TESTModule", author= "Oracle Corp.", version="1.0")


@ModuleInfo.plugin("wb.sqlide.test_module", caption= "Test module", input= [wbinputs.currentQueryEditor()], pluginMenu= "SQL/Utilities")
@ModuleInfo.export(grt.INT, grt.classes.db_query_QueryEditor)
def test_module(editor):
    editor.replaceContents("test")
    return 0
```